# Does a Creative Commons "Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 Unported License" classify a nonprofit as a "commercial entity"?

Tags: legal, licenses, creative-commons

If something [this license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/) applies to is used by a nonprofit, is the nonprofit considered a "commercial entity"?

Because the license says:

> "NonCommercial — You may not use the material for commercial purposes."

and

> "A commercial use is one primarily intended for commercial advantage or monetary compensation."

Or does that depend on how that something is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although a [nonprofit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonprofit_organization) organization is a legal entity with certain tax exemptions and possible charitable status, that classification doesn't necessarily mean all reuse would be considered *noncommercial*.

As indicated in the [FAQ for the Creative Commons](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Does_my_use_violate_the_NonCommercial_clause_of_the_licenses.3F):

> If you are a nonprofit or charitable organization, your use of an NC-licensed work could still run afoul of the NC restriction, and if you are a for-profit entity, your use of an NC-licensed work does not necessarily mean you have violated the term. Whether a use is commercial will depend on the specifics of the situation and the intentions of the user.

As stated below in the [Creative Commons wiki documentation for 
NonCommercial interpretation](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/NonCommercial_interpretation), it's not the category or class of reuser, it's the intended use that determines this:

> **NonCommercial turns on the use, not the identity of the reuser.** The
>   definition of NonCommercial depends on the primary purpose for which
>   the work is used, not on the category or class of reuser.

In terms of what's considered to be *commercial* use, the Creative Commons points to a survey they conducted in 2008 on the meanings of commercial and noncommercial use. The [Executive Summary](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Defining_Noncommercial) of this study indicates that commercial use is generally perceived to be `uses that earn users money or involve online advertising`. It's advisable to refer to that survey for more details on the distinction between the two.

**In summary:** It's not the *reuser* (i.e., nonprofits or for-profits), but the intended *use* that qualifies it as either commercial or noncommercial.